# How do I assign functions to controller buttons using the XR Interaction toolkit?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Assigning functions to buttons using `OVRManager` is very easy.

```cs
  void Update(){

       if (OVRInput.GetDown(OVRInput.RawButton.Y))
       {
          //Do something
       }
    }
```

How can I implement something similar to the above using the XR Interaction toolkit?

Comment: afaik it uses the new [Input System](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.inputsystem@1.5/manual/index.html) -> you define you actions and then subscribe to events rather then doing poll checks every frame